# radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (2+(-1)^k)^kx^{2k}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (2+(-1)^k)^kx^{2k}$$

what i have done is that  : for $j$ odd , $a_j =0$

for $j = 2k$ ($k$ is even), $a_j=3^k$

for $j = 2k$ ($k$ is odd), $a_j=1^k$

so $R = 1/ \limsup |3^k|^{1/2k} = 3^{-1/2} $

but the book says $R=1/3$

Comment: For summations, you want to use `\sum`, for example `\sum_{k = 0}^\infty` for $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty$. You can also use the \$ for formatting in the title.

Comment: Anyhow, the book is wrong.

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: wade 4th edition introduction to analysis  7.3.1 b)

Comment: See [Erratum (88)](https://www.math.utk.edu/~wade/pics/4EDERROR.pdf) from the "Misprints for the fourth edition" list on Wade's website.

Comment: I can't open what you upload but i guess in this time the book is wrong

Comment: Anyway thank you very much

Comment: @nien In the PDF linked: "(88) p. 247, Exercise 7.3.1b: Replace the exponent $2k$ by $k$." (It's not my upload, but a list of mistakes and typos from the book, maintained by the author.)

Comment: Ohoh ok thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is wrong, your answer is correct.

Moreover, this is a known mistake: namely, the [list of errata](https://www.math.utk.edu/~wade/pics/4EDERROR.pdf) maintained for *An Introduction to Analysis* (4th edition) on his website by the author, William R. Wade, contains the following line:

> (88) p. 247, Exercise 7.3.1b: Replace the exponent $2k$ by $k$.